# QListWidget crash when reusing the widget associated with item

Tags: c++, qt

I have a custom simple widget inheriting from QWidget and I add it to a QListWidget like this :

```
void MainWindow::AddToWidgetList(const QString &tag, const QString &html)
{
    HtmlItem *html_item = new HtmlItem();
    html_item->set_tag(tag);
    html_item->set_html(html);
    connect(html_item, SIGNAL(RemoveIt(uintptr_t)), this, SLOT(on_RmBtn_clicked(uintptr_t)));
    QListWidgetItem *list_item = new QListWidgetItem();
    html_item->set_list_item(list_item);
    list_item->setSizeHint(html_item->sizeHint());
    ui->CodeBlocks->addItem(list_item);
    ui->CodeBlocks->setItemWidget(list_item, html_item);
}
```

I then want to move the selected element up when a button is pressed

```
void MainWindow::on_UpArrowBtn_clicked()
{
    if (ui->CodeBlocks->count() < 2)
        return;
    int current_row = ui->CodeBlocks->currentRow();
    if (current_row == 0)
        return;
    HtmlItem *item_widget = (HtmlItem*)ui->CodeBlocks->itemWidget(ui->CodeBlocks->item(current_row));
    QListWidgetItem *item = ui->CodeBlocks->takeItem(current_row);
    ui->CodeBlocks->insertItem(current_row - 1, item);
    ui->CodeBlocks->setItemWidget(item, item_widget);
}
```

but I get crash in this line :

```
ui->CodeBlocks->setItemWidget(item, item_widget);
```

Comment: After you moved the list item up you try to set the same item widget again. Thus the old item widget might get destructed which is the new one (not sure if Qt handles this). You can create a copy of your list widget and add the copy.

Comment: but shouldn't the old widget be released when the item is released ? if no then how can I release it ?

Comment: You just take the item from the list and insert it again at a different row. `takeItem()` doesn't release the item.

Comment: the doc says : "takeItem : Removes and returns the item from the given row in the list widget; otherwise returns nullptr. Items removed from a list widget will not be managed by Qt, and will need to be deleted manually." so the item is released and can be inserted again . when I try to insert it again it works well and is moved up but it loses its widget .

Comment: "when I try to insert it again it works well and is moved up but it loses its widget" --> Thus you need a copy because if the widget has been removed either by `takeItem() or later by insertItem()` it has been destructed and you can't add the same widget again which you previously saved by it's pointer.

Comment: Set a breakpoint to your `HtmlItem` destructor and see if it will be called as a result of a item up move.

Comment: no you misunderstood my comment. I mean when I move the item up without using setItemWidget it is moved but there is no widget in it as I didn't set a widget for the new inserted item . And copying the widget works also but I prefer not to copy especially when I don't know what will happen to the previous one will it get deleted or left away causing memory leaks? The documentation isn't clear and doesn't talk about the state of inner widget in this case . Also I try to evade debugging as I'm using qt creator with a release build of qt 5.13 and debugging in qt creator is a headache for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example shows what is happening. Basically, the rules are like this:

Calling `setItemWidget` transfers the ownership of the Item-Widget to the `QListWidget` instance. Hence, it is `QListWidget`'s responsibility to destroy the set Item-Widget.

Now, `QListWidget` has no member, which allows to withdraw the ownership of a set Item-Widget. The only option one has is to create a new Item-Widget with the same properties like Item-Widget about to removed.

Note, that the Item-Widget ist deleted later after returning to the event loop, which happens by calling `deleteLater()` inside of `takeItem`. Hence, it is valid to access `label` till the end of the slot.

If you are not happy with this behavior, you are still able to switch to a `QListView` class with your own delegate. Albeit this seems to be more work, it is the more extensible approach.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    QApplication app(argc, args);
    auto frame = new QFrame;
    auto listWidget = new QListWidget;
    for (auto iter=0; iter<10; iter++)
    {
        auto label = new QLabel(QString("Item-%1").arg(iter));
        auto item = new QListWidgetItem();      
        listWidget->addItem(item);
        listWidget->setItemWidget(item, label); // listWidget becomes the owner of label
    }
    auto moveUp = new QPushButton("Move Up");
    frame->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
    frame->layout()->addWidget(listWidget);
    frame->layout()->addWidget(moveUp);
    frame->show();
    QObject::connect(moveUp, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]()
    {
            auto row = listWidget->currentRow();
            auto item=listWidget->currentItem();
            if (!item) return;
            if (row == 0) return;

            auto label = qobject_cast<QLabel*>(listWidget->itemWidget(item));
            if (!label) return;

            QObject::connect(label, &QLabel::destroyed, []()
                {
                    qDebug() << "Destroyed"; // takeItem calls deleteLater on itemWidget
                });
            auto myItem=listWidget->takeItem(row);
            listWidget->insertItem(row-1,myItem);
            listWidget->setItemWidget(item, new QLabel(label->text())); // copy content of itemWidget and create new widget
            listWidget->setCurrentRow(row-1);
    });
    app.exec();
}
```

Comment: yes copying works as I said . but it's bad that qlistwidget doesn't enable to release the widget of the item

Comment: @dev65: I think it is designed for very simple use cases. You should consider to switch to `QListView` and `QStandardItemModel`. It is not so hard to use anyway.